# how to know grouping values in pivot chart in Hyperion designer

Tags: hyperion

I have a chart which has query,result and pivot. pivot has 3 part side labels,top labels and facts.
Some user selected few data in side label and make them a group, I dont know what those values are.
Can somebody let me know how to find grouping values in Hyperion Designer 8.5.

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: @deepak_nigam There's just not enough information to go on.  Do you have some screenshots?  What kind of group are you talking about?  When you say "some user selected few data in side label" what do you mean?  Was there a developer before you?  Was this someone using your file and made changes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that what you have is a pivot table where someone created a drilldown by right-clicking and selecting hide.  And you want to know what they hid.  Unfortunately, even if you're the one that hid the values, you can't get that information back without showing everything.  This is just one of those Hyperion quirks: it assumes that people using Designer are individual developers who aren't going to be hiding and renaming things without remembering the original values.  The only way to get it back is to do some detective work by showing everything and trying to replicate the table.